# Back button doesn't work on 3rd page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, mobile-safari

I have the following code to change a page :

```
$.mobile.changePage("<?php echo base_url(); ?>mobile/products_by_phone/"+ 
$('#phone_number').val(),  {
 type: "GET",
transition: "flip"} );
```

Now inside that page if I press the back button, it returns to my initial page but if I invoke another changePage call, this one :

```
$.mobile.changePage("<?php echo base_url(); ?>mobile/pay_method_dialog",  {
type: "POST",
data: data,
transition: "flip"} );
```

It changes fine but then when I press the back button I just see in the URL: `mybaseurl/mypage#products`
When products is the ID of the page I load in the 2nd request but it doesn't change back, only if I press again the page changes to the original.

How can I fix this?

- I've tried instead invoking a call of anchors linking to those pages but that didn't work.
- All those pages have valid HTML tags (although I include all the scripts again in those pages)

Comment: Please, show your final (after php generation) html markup for those pages or better yet make a jsFiddle.

Comment: Well i got tired with not finding a solution so i gave up on changing pages with animation and just reloaded each page.